# QGIS 2.14 Composer incorrectly renders svg text position

Tags: qgis, print-composer, svg, text

I just noticed that SVG rendering in composer since upgrade to QGIS 2.14 is incorrectly handling some text placement.  I have an SVG compass rose, which was rendering fine before upgrading to 2.14 (Essen).

Before upgrade -

[image: Rose Correct]

Now as displayed in Composer, 2.14 -

[image]

Note that some text is correct, the problem seems to be with the numerals arrayed around the circles, which have been transformed by rotation.

This svg was created in Inkscape, exported as a standard svg.  It is rendered correctly in any browsers and other viewing software I have tried.  It also rendered correctly in QGIS version 2.12.  I am using both Inkscape & QGIS on the same computer, running Ubuntu 14.04, so referenced font is available.

As a workaround, I have exported the svg from Inkscape to a png bitmap, which displays fine in Composer.  Another workaround is to convert the problem text to paths in inkscape, which then render as expected, but that seems a little clumsy.

Has anyone else experienced this, or have any ideas on the problem?  I really like the ability to create detailed svgs in Inkscape to greatly enhance the graphic capabilities of Print Composer, but not so handy if I can't rely on the text rendering.

Here is a copy of the problem svg, in case some curious soul wants to check for themselves - [NauticalRoseSJ_ink.svg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4HehN0gYoMoNGhnbDFTdGstR2s)

Comment: I'd recommend opening a ticket on the bug tracker with your SVG attached

Comment: I will file a bug ticket on hub.qgis.org as soon as I can get an OSGeo account.  The OSGeo account signup page has been showing "under maintenance" for last few days.

Comment: @underdark, could you point me to site where I can get proper OSGeo account for access to hub.qgis.org?  Got approved for an account for OSGeo Wiki, but those credentials not accepted at hub.qgis.org.  This link, for account request, has not been working - https://www2.osgeo.org/cgi-bin/ldap_create_user.py

Comment: Seems like signup is currently disabled due to spam issues: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/sac/2016-May/006688.html

Comment: Opened bug ticket - #14794 - on QGIS bug tracker.  Hopefully this will be an easy fix.

Comment: I have had a similar issue with two svg north arrows I designed 3 years ago in Inkscape.  No problems with them until I upgraded to Essen 2.14.1.  Now the N appears well to the right of the arrow point in print composer.  The svg files open as expected in Inkscape.  This problem occurs in both old composers opened in Essen, and new ones.  Now using 2.14.2 (32 bit - for compatibility) with no resolution to this issue, running on laptop with Windows 10 home 64 bit.  If not resolved shortly I will revert to Pisa (Essen is also hanging on load up - another issue).

Comment: Update on this - Bug ticket has been addressed and closed, see - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/2265115f8003857e538f07287c1337fed463a39c

Comment: I will report this as solved when I get the update and test.

Answer (score 2):

As @underdark suggested, it does seem like a bug. Another workaround is to, wierdly, load your svg file in the earlier QGIS version and save it as a new svg file:

[image: Earlier QGIS version]

Then load this newly saved svg file into QGIS 2.14:

[image: QGIS 2.14.1]

Hopefully your text will be aligned correctly.

---

*Tested with QGIS 2.13.3-Lyon and QGIS 2.14.1-Essen*.

Comment: thanks for taking time to check this out.  Good to know I wasn't imagining this.  Enough workarounds to keep working, but clearly would be great to have this fixed.

Comment: @ZanStrausz - Most welcome, hopefully it will be fixed in the next version =)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now resolved.  I just upgraded to QGIS 2.16 (Nødebo) and tested.  Now my original svg text aligns properly, just as created in Inkscape.

There was a bug introduced at some point, this was fixed by Nyall Dawson, thanks much.
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/2265115f8003857e538f07287c1337fed463a39c

Also, I did test in QGIS 2.12, and it the svg rendering was working fine in that version; it broke sometime between then and version 2.14.